# how can I close browser after reach scenarion in cucumber by java , my code is not working

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have issue with cucumber hooks
I want to close browser after each scenario , in the following code when I run my scenarios , all of them will run in the same browser.

Could you please check my code and tell me what's wrong ??

**Note:** *that i didn't write any thing in after and initialize value for dunit is false*

```
@Before
public void beforeAll(Scenario Scenario) {
    if (!dunit) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                System.out.println("Scenario " + Scenario.getName()+ " has been finished" );

                PageFactory.instance().getWebDriver();

                PageFactory._driver.quit();
        }
    });
;

        System.out.println("Scenario " + Scenario.getName()+ " has been started");
        dunit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just check if `driver` is not null in the `@after` and close. Make sure to launch the browser in the `@before` or `@background` or `in your step`.

Comment: i did it already , i got error session id is null

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, make sure to have  check if driver is null, if not then close.

Comment: same old same old i got error invalid session / session id is null

Comment: any help guys ?

Comment: Are you getting invalid session/session id even when the session(browser) is still open?

Comment: @supputuri no browser the browser will  close

Comment: If the browser is already closed before hitting `@after` hook, then it's expected to show the error message unless you wrap the close in condition.

Comment: i tried with all possible ways but the problem still exist

Comment: any help guys ?

Comment: i still stuck on this issue , how i can solve it , thanks in advance

Comment: any help guys  ??

Comment: did you checked if `PageFactory._driver` is null?

Comment: yes i did , i did all possible cases to check if the driver null or not , i dont now if this bug is getting becase of a bug from selenium it self ?

Comment: what should i do to fix this issue

Comment: what was the value of `PageFactory._driver`?

Comment: not null before quit , if you can help me this isy facebook account if you want to check       tofailhiary thank you

Comment: finally , i fixed the issue 
the problem was because of my test ,
the messing point was always the page using the driver stored already in that page 

this code is the problem 

    public My365Requests my365RequestsPage() {
        if (_my365Requests == null) {
            _my365Requests = new My365Requests(getWebDriver());
        }
        return _my365Requests;
    }
and the fix we don't need to check if the page is null or not 
thank you